# Symfony 4.x public dir rename to public_html

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I got a little struggle with renaming dir to public_html for web host.
According to latest [tutorial](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/override_dir_structure.html) I'm trying to successfully rename it, but every time when i'm trying to run local server using console command I'm getting an error:
`[ERROR] The document root directory ".../.../App/public" does not exist.`

I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong with code. But I don't know where. I'm very beginner with Symfony.

Here's my code from composer.json:

```
"extra": {
    "symfony": {
        "allow-contrib": false,
        "require": "4.2.*",   
    }
    "public-dir": "public_html"
},
```

Did I understood something wrong with it?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the index.php file is the first file being run (by the webserver) you should just be able to rename the `public` directory to `public_html` and it will work, and not need to change anything in the composer.json (though how that would affect the framework code, without at least running any composer-scripts, I do not know).

I've just created a new Symfony 4.2.3 project, and done nothing more than renaming the directory, and running (most) bin/console commands are not affected.

The in-built server will have issues, but you can tell it which directory to use as the docroot with:

```
mv public public_html
bin/console server:start --docroot=public_html/
```

> [OK] Server listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000

The changes to composer.json are not required.

Answer (score 2):

If the code snippet represents exactly what you have in your composer.json then I have noticed that it is not correctly formatted json file.  In the "extra", after the value of "symfony" key, you need to put a separator "," then in the next line you may add more key:value pairs. AS in:

```
"extra": {
    "symfony": {
        "allow-contrib": false,
        "require": "4.2.*",   
    },
    "public-dir": "new_public_html_dirname"
}
```

A not well formatted json file will prevent it from being executed.  I hope it helps.

It is important to run composer update.

```
composer update
```